# CSS column widths: "as wide as needed" and "whatever's left"

Tags: css

I have a webpage that looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style=white-space:nowrap>
            lots of content...
        </td>
        <td>
            some more content
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This works nicely. The left column takes up as much width as it needs and the right column takes up as much as it can.  The right column includes a lot of automatic line-wrapping.

I'd like to do this in pure CSS because semantically speaking there's nothing tabular.  But everything I try either requires hard-coding widths or puts the right column underneath the left column.  Is there a way?

Comment: Actually, the `min-content` value for `width` would be the solution to your problem — a shame that it is still experimental. http://demosthenes.info/blog/662/Design-From-the-Inside-Out-With-CSS-MinContent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float the left column, and make the right column non-floated with `overflow:hidden`. This will cause the right column to automatically fill the remaining width, without wrapping around below the left column.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/E6Ard/1/)

```
.column1 {
    float: left;
}
.column2 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This trick tested fine in all browsers except IE6 (which shouldn't matter at this point).

Comment: That works.  How does "overflow" do this, though?  Isn't it supposed to be about dealing with content not fitting in a box?

Comment: @dspeyer: Here's an article describing how this works: http://colinaarts.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden/#making-room-for-floats

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `display:table-cell` rule to simulate the table layout.

```
<div style=white-space:nowrap>lots of content... lots of content... lots of content... lots of content... lots of content... lots of content... lots of content...</div>
<div>some more content</div>

div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/gqNTX/)**